# How could I get PHP to decrypt some files in memory and then make the client download those files?

Tags: php, file, download

I'm currently learning PHP and programming in general. I'm currently writing my first website where I have a simple login system and users can enter some data in plain text. Upon entry, PHP encrypts this data.

I want to add a feature where users can then download an unencrypted copy of the data and I want to do it in such a way that the files on disk remain encrypted the entire time and an unencrypted copy is not stored anywhere.

At the moment I should be able to decrypt the data line by line and store it in an array, but I don't know what I could do once I get to that point. Is there a way for PHP to treat an array as if it was just a text file and then ask the client to download it? Or maybe I could just somehow stream the array to a file on the client, line by line?

I have no code to show at the moment as I'm still trying to work out in my head how it will all be structured.

The solution must also be portable between a windows and Linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the encrypted file is plain text. Second, writing in pseudo-code, because I do not know your solution

First, you need to decrypt the data in something that can be `echo`ed to the user. Or more generally, something that is represented as a `String`.

I am doing something simillar with PDF files, so I am showing the similar on TXT file:

```
$encryptedData = $this->getEncryptedData(); // load what needs to be decrypted. Pseudocode
$filename = 'download.txt'; // file name to download. Will be download.txt
$contents = $this->decrypt($encryptedData) // $contents should be String. Decryption is pseudocode

header("Content-Type: text/plain"); //set header as TXT file
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename={$filename}"); //force download prompt from the browser
echo $contents; //print decrypted data to TXT
exit; //stop script after download
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what "my solution" is, I'm just using PHP with Apache2. This is the code I wrote to try and test to see if doing that works https://pastebin.com/vKH920aG

It doesn't seem to do anything when I go to that page on my laptop after starting up apache, no download prompt or anything. Not on Firefox, at least.

Comment: Nvm just saw the syntax error I made, should be ?> not <?, now it works great. Thank you :)